# getting duplicities <a href> src (jquery)

Tags: jquery, href, jquery-wrap

I use this Jquery script, and it should extract the href source, and parsing the text from the html var but for some reason I got duplicities...

code:

```js
var html = '<p>lorem ipsum<a href="sound.mp3">Sound</a></p>';

var $html = $('<div/>').html(html);
$html.find("a[href$='mp3']").filter(function () {
    var $mp3 = $(this);
    return $mp3.attr('href') 
}).wrap(function () {
    return ' <test="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">';
});

html = $html.html();

alert(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Code:

```js
var html = '<p>lorem ipsum<a href="sound.mp3">Sound</a></p>';

var $html = $('<div/>').html(html);
$html.find("a[href$='mp3']").filter(function () {
    var $mp3 = $(this);
    $mp3.after('<test>' + $mp3.attr('href') + '</test>');
    $mp3.remove();
});

html = $html.html();

alert(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `<p>lorem ipsum test="sound.mp3"></a></p>` is not a valid `HTML` markup, if you want output like this: `<p>lorem ipsum test="sound.mp3"</p>` then above updated code will work for you

Comment: While adding `<test="sound.mp3">` to `DOM` it's corresponding closing tag '</test="sound.mp3">' will also get added to `DOM`, so you can't add only `<test="sound.mp3">`, however if you want you can add `<test>sound.mp3</test>` to `DOM`

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$html.find("a[href$='mp3']").filter(function () {
```

you are just missing '**]**' after `mp3` and optionally you can change

```
return 'test="' + this.getAttribute('href') + '"></a>';
```

to this

```
return 'test="' + this.attr('href') + '"></a>';
```